# Google Sheets Query Drop Down Filtered Returned Values Not Resetting

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, dropdown

Using the following code, I've been able to query a single column properly from my dataset where B2 and B3 are drop downs that I use to filter and D1 is just a header (I have multiple queries side by side that use the same filters)

```
=IFERROR(QUERY('Input Sheet'!$A:$E, "select A where B = '"&$B$2&"' and C = '"&D$1&"' and D ='"&$B$3&"'",0),"")
```

I've tried looking it up and when I see other people use the Query function, their search area will reset upon changing their drop down filters. What I mean is, if the first query returns 4 rows and the second returns 1, only my first row will update for the query.

Updated to include sample data and video. Sorry I can't post directly into thread.

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKeoW.png) (date is excluded since it isn't relevant to my query)

[Dropdowns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwJoE.png)

[Query Table and Filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQ2Lu.png)

[Video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hFRORgJMq_B3W9ol5ekAL-3jDxxVv7F5/view?usp=sharing)

So if my first query has 4 rows and my next query returns only 1 row, the last 3 rows will not update.

So for example, lets say my first query returns the following:

```
10

19

32

41
```

Changing a filter will return

```
23

19

32

41
```

But in reality, the query should only return 23, the rest of the values are from the previous query. None of the videos I've watched have this problem (so none have addressed my issue)

If I change my filters to something that should return nothing (no data entries) I get the following:

```
"" (Empty Cell, Null etc)

19

32

41
```

My data source is formatted like the below

```
A   B   C   D

1   2   3   4

w   x   y   z
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share some sample data in a sheet with the expected output? It will be easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Updated the post with screenshots and a video. Hopefully this makes it easier to understand

Comment: I have tried to recreate your situation but it updates correctly for me. Maybe you could share a sample project where this issue reproduces?